# Graph Library in C

Tags: c, graph

Could you guys please review the Graph Library I developed in C? [It's also on GitHub](https://github.com/konerukaushik/Graphlib)

```
#include "graph.h"

/*Function:
 * Graph_node_in_adjacency
 *
 * In this function we verify whether the node is
 * present in adjacency List of a vertex
 *
 * Input:
 *      Graph_edges_t
 *      vertex_number_t
 *
 * Output:
 *      bool - True  - IF Present
 *             False - IF not Present
 */
bool
Graph_node_in_adjacency(Graph_edges_t *adjacency_list, vertex_number_t node) {
  
  Graph_edges_t         *runner;

  runner  = adjacency_list;

  while(runner != NULL) {
    if (runner->target == node) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    runner = runner->next;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

/*
 * Function:
 *  Graph_has_edge
 *
 * In this function we validate whether
 * there is a edge between
 * two vetices
 *
 * Input:
 *    Graph_t
 *    vertex_number_t
 *    vertex_number_t
 *
 * Output:
 *     bool True <-- If there is Edge
 *          False <-- If there is no Edge
 */
bool
Graph_has_edge(Graph_t *G, vertex_number_t S, vertex_number_t D) {

  Graph_vertices_t    *vertex;

  vertex  = Graph_get_vertex(G,S);
  if (vertex == NULL) {
    LOG_DEBUG("Vertex :%d has no edges",S);
    return FALSE;
  }

  return Graph_node_in_adjacency(vertex->adjacency_list,D);

}

/*
 * Function:
 *  Graph_node_in_priority_list
 *
 *  In this function we verify
 *  whether node is already present in 
 *  priority_list before appending to
 *  priority_list
 *
 * Input
 *    Graph_priority_t
 *    vertex_number_t
 *
 * output
 *    True (If already present)
 *    False (If not present)
 */
bool
Graph_node_in_priority_list(Graph_priority_t *prio,
                              vertex_number_t node) {
    Graph_priority_t    *S;

    S = prio;

    while(S != NULL) {
      if (S->vertex == node) {
        return TRUE;
      }
      S = S->next;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

/* Function:
 * Graph_dump_prio_list
 *
 * In this function we dump complete Priority 
 * List
 *
 * Input:
 *    Graph_priority_t *S
 *
 * Output:
 *    none
 */
void
Graph_dump_prio_list(Graph_priority_t *S) {

  Graph_priority_t      *runner = S;


  if (S == NULL) {
    LOG_DEBUG("Priority List is NULL");
    return;
  }

  printf("<-----Prio List ----->\n");
  while(S != NULL) {
    printf(" Node -> %d\n",S->vertex);
    S = S->next;
  }
  printf("<-------------------->\n");


  return;
}

/*
 * Function:
 * Graph_get_vertex
 *
 * In this function we vertex pointer
 * from graph
 *
 * Input:
 *      Graph_t   
 *      vertex_number_t
 *
 * Output:
 *      Graph_vertices_t
 */
Graph_vertices_t *
Graph_get_vertex(Graph_t *G, vertex_number_t node) {
  
    Graph_vertices_t    *runner;

    runner  = G->vertices_list;

    while(runner != NULL && runner->interface_number != node) {
      runner = runner->next;
    }

    return runner;
}

/*
 * Function:
 * Graph_add_edge_to_vertex
 *
 * In this function we append new_edge to
 * the adjacency list of vertices list
 *
 * Input: Graph_edges_t     adjacency_list
 *        Graph_edges_t     new_edge
 * output:
 *        Graph_edges_t* (Graph Vertex adjacencyList)
 */
Graph_edges_t *
Graph_add_edge_to_vertex(Graph_edges_t  *adjacency_list,
                         Graph_edges_t  *new_edge) {

  Graph_edges_t      *runner; /* To Parse through to vertices_list */
  
  if (adjacency_list == NULL) {
    free(runner);
    return new_edge;
  }

  runner = adjacency_list;

  /* Parse till we reach end of Adjacency List */
  while(runner->next != NULL) {
    runner = runner->next;
  }

  /* Append the New edge to List */
  runner->next = new_edge;

  return adjacency_list;
}

/* 
 * Function:
 * Graph_add_edge_template
 *
 * In this function we create new Edge Object
 * to append into the vertices Adjacency List
 * So, We consider destination and weight only
 *
 * Input:
 *      vertex_number_t destination (Destination Vertex)
 *      edge_weight_t   weight  (Weight of edge)
 * Output:
 *      Graph_edges_t  (new edge Object)
 */
Graph_edges_t *
Graph_add_edge_template(vertex_number_t Destination,
                        edge_weight_t   weight) {

    Graph_edges_t      *temp;

    temp = (Graph_edges_t *)malloc(sizeof(Graph_edges_t));

    if (temp == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("Unable to allocate memory for Edge with Dest:%d",Destination);
      goto destroy;
    }

    temp->target = Destination;
    temp->weight = weight;
    temp->next   = NULL;

    return temp;
    
destroy:
    free(temp);
    return NULL;
}

/* Function: Graph_append_edge
 * In this function we add edges
 * to a Specifc Graph
 *
 * Input:
 *      G <-- Graph In which we Need to Append the Edge
 *      Source <-- This will Source
 *      weight <-- Edge Weight
 *      Destination <-- This is Destination
 * Output:
 *      Modified G
 */
Graph_t *
Graph_append_edge(Graph_t *G, vertex_number_t S, vertex_number_t D,
                  edge_weight_t weight) {

  Graph_edges_t       *new_edge;
  Graph_vertices_t    *vertex;
  int                  found = 0;

  new_edge   =  Graph_add_edge_template(D, weight);
  if (new_edge == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Unable to Create edge Template for Source %d - Destination %d\n",S,D);
    goto destroy;
  }

  vertex  = Graph_get_vertex(G, S);
  if (vertex == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Unable to find vertex: %d",S);
    goto destroy;
  }

  /* If we are unable to add certain edge, Notify User
   * and Proceed to execute further
   */
  vertex->adjacency_list = Graph_add_edge_to_vertex(vertex->adjacency_list, new_edge);

  return G;

destroy:
  free(vertex);
  free(new_edge);
}
      
/*
 * Function: Graph_add_edge
 *
 * This function is the API for 
 * adding Edge
 *
 * Input:
 *      G <-- Graph In which we Need to Append the Edge
 *      Source <-- This will a 
 *      Destination <-- 
 *      is_directed <-- if then add to specific one vertices
 *                      else add to both vertices
 *                     
 */
Graph_t *
Graph_add_edge(Graph_t *G, vertex_number_t S, vertex_number_t D,  
                edge_weight_t weight, bool is_directed) {

  
  G = Graph_append_edge(G,S,D,weight);

  if (!is_directed) {
    G = Graph_append_edge(G,D,S,weight);
  }

  return G;
}
  

/*
 * Function: Graph_add_vertices_template()
 *
 * In this function we create 
 * single vertex and return it
 *
 * Input : none
 * output: Graph_vertices_t object or NULL
 */
Graph_vertices_t *
Graph_add_vertices_template() {
  
    Graph_vertices_t     *V;

    V = (Graph_vertices_t *)malloc(sizeof(Graph_vertices_t));
    if (V == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("Unable to assign Memory for Vertices");
      goto destroy;
    }

    /* Initialize V with template */
    V->interface_number   = NaN;
    V->is_visited         = FALSE;
    V->adjacency_list     = NULL;
    V->min_distance       = NaN;
    V->next               = NULL;


    return V;

destroy:
    free(V);
    return NULL;
}

/*
 * Function: Graph_add_vertices
 *
 * In this function we create 
 * single vertex and return it
 *
 * Input : N <- No Of vertices to create
 *         G <- To Which we need to append N vertices
 * output: Graph_vertices_t object or NULL
 */
Graph_vertices_t *
Graph_add_vertices(Graph_t *G, int no_of_vertices) {
  
    Graph_vertices_t     *V        = NULL;
    Graph_vertices_t     *runner   = NULL;
    int                   iterator = G->total_vertices;

    V = G->vertices_list;

    while(V != NULL && V->next != NULL) {
      V = V->next;
    }

    while(iterator < no_of_vertices + G->total_vertices) {
      LOG_DEBUG("Memory Appending for vertices %d",iterator);
      LOG_DEBUG("Total required vertices %d, Present vertices %d",no_of_vertices, G->total_vertices);

      runner  = Graph_add_vertices_template();
      if (runner == NULL) {
        LOG_ERR("Runner is NULL for iterator %d",iterator);
        goto destroy;
      }

      LOG_DEBUG("Appending Vertex with ID:%d",iterator);
      runner->interface_number = iterator;

      if (V == NULL) {
          V                = runner;
          G->vertices_list = V;
      } else {
          V->next = runner;
          V       = V->next;
      }
    
      runner = runner->next;

      iterator = iterator + 1;
    }

    G->total_vertices += iterator;

    return G->vertices_list;

destroy:
    free(V);
    free(runner);
    return G->vertices_list;;
}

/* 
 * In this function we create 
 * Graph Object and initiate basic template
 *
 * Input : none
 * Output: Graph_t Object
 */
Graph_t *
Graph_init_template() {

    Graph_t         *G = NULL;

    /* 
     * Allocate Memory for Graph Object 
     */
    G   =   (Graph_t *) malloc(sizeof(Graph_t));
    if (G == NULL) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to allocate memory");
        goto destroy;
    }

    /* 
     * Initialize variables
     */
    G->total_vertices   =   0;
    G->total_edges      =   0;
    G->vertices_list    =   NULL;
    G->source           =   NaN;
    G->is_directed      =   FALSE;

    return G;

destroy:
    free(G);
    return NULL;
}


/* 
 * In this function we create 
 * Graph Object and initiate basic template
 * and Initialize N Vertices and 
 * set if it is a Directed or Not (Passed as Argument)
 *
 * Input : int no_of_vertices
 *         bool is_directed
 * Output: Graph_t Object
 */
Graph_t *
Graph_init(int no_of_vertices, bool is_directed) {
    
    Graph_t             *G      = NULL;

    G   =   Graph_init_template();
    if(G == NULL) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to Initialize %d vertices",no_of_vertices);
        goto destroy;
    }

    Graph_add_vertices(G, no_of_vertices);
    if (G->vertices_list  == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("Unable to create %d vertices",no_of_vertices);
      goto destroy;
    }

    G->is_directed = is_directed; 

    return G;

destroy:
    free(G);
    return NULL;
}


/*
 * Function
 * Graph_dump_vertices
 *
 * In this function we display Vertices with 
 * Adjacency List
 * 
 * Input:
 *      Graph_vertices_t  - Vertices
 *      print_adjacency   - True/False (If adjacency needs
 *                                      to be printed)
 * Output:
 *      no-return
 */
void
Graph_dump_vertices(const Graph_vertices_t *V, bool print_adjacency) {
  
    Graph_edges_t       *adjacency_list;

    if (V == NULL) {
      return;
    }

    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("| Vertex ID : %4d      |\n",V->interface_number);
    printf("| is_visited: %s     |\n",V->is_visited?"TRUE":"FALSE");
    if (V->min_distance == NaN) {
      printf("| min_dis   : NaN       |\n");
    } else {
      printf("| min_dis   : %3lu       |\n",(V->min_distance));
    }
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    if (print_adjacency) {
      if (V->adjacency_list != NULL) {
        printf("-------------------------\n");
        printf("Adjacency ");
        adjacency_list = V->adjacency_list;
        while(adjacency_list != NULL) {
          printf("%3d",adjacency_list->target);
          adjacency_list = adjacency_list->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("-------------------------\n");

      }
    }

    return;
}

/*
 * Function:
 * Graph_display_graph
 *
 * In this function we display complete graph 
 * Information
 *
 * Input: 
 *      Graph_t  - Graph Pointer
 *
 * Output:
 *      NULL
 */
 void
 Graph_display_graph(const Graph_t *G) {
  
   Graph_vertices_t         *V_parse;

   if (G == NULL) {
    LOG_INFO("Provided Graph to display is NULL");
    goto destroy;
   }

   if (G->total_vertices == 0 ) {
     LOG_INFO("There are no vertices in the Graph");
     goto destroy;
   }

   if (G->vertices_list == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("Unable to retrieve interfaces info from Graph");
      goto destroy;
   }

   V_parse  = G->vertices_list;

   while (V_parse != NULL) {
     Graph_dump_vertices(V_parse, TRUE);
     V_parse = V_parse->next;
   }
 
destroy:

   free(V_parse);
   return;
 }


Graph_vertices_t *
Graph_Dj_get_next_vertex(Graph_t *G, Graph_priority_t *priority_list) {

  if (priority_list == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  return Graph_get_vertex(G,priority_list->vertex); 
}

Graph_priority_t *
Graph_get_priority_list_template() {

  Graph_priority_t      *temp;

  temp  = (Graph_priority_t *) malloc(sizeof(Graph_priority_t));
  if (temp == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("Unable to allocate memory for new Prio List");
      goto destroy;
  }

  temp->vertex = 0;
  temp->next   = NULL;

  return temp;

destroy:
  free(temp);
  return NULL;
}

bool
Graph_Dj_set_min_distance(Graph_t *G,
                          edge_weight_t weight, 
                          vertex_number_t vertex_ID) {

  Graph_vertices_t            *vertex;

  vertex  = Graph_get_vertex(G,vertex_ID);
  if (vertex == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Unable to find vertex with ID :%d ",vertex_ID);
    return FALSE;
  }


  if (vertex->min_distance > weight) {
      vertex->min_distance = weight;
      return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

Graph_priority_t *
Graph_get_priority_list(Graph_t *G,
                         Graph_priority_t  *priority_list, 
                          Graph_vertices_t *vertex) {

  Graph_edges_t             *adjacency_list;
  Graph_priority_t          *prio_runner;
  Graph_priority_t          *temp;

  /* Need to make sure that vertex sent is proper */
  assert(vertex);

  adjacency_list  = vertex->adjacency_list;
  prio_runner     = priority_list;

  while(prio_runner != NULL && prio_runner->next != NULL ) {
    prio_runner = prio_runner->next;
  }

  while(adjacency_list != NULL) {
    /* Add to Priority List only if 
     * vertex distance + weight is less than existing 
     * new vertex min distance
     */
    if (Graph_Dj_set_min_distance(G, 
                        (vertex->min_distance+adjacency_list->weight),
                          adjacency_list->target)) {
      if (!Graph_node_in_priority_list(priority_list, adjacency_list->target)) { 
        temp  =  Graph_get_priority_list_template(); 
        temp->vertex = adjacency_list->target;
        if (priority_list == NULL || prio_runner == NULL) {
          priority_list = temp;
          prio_runner   = temp;
        } else {
          prio_runner->next = temp;
          prio_runner   = prio_runner->next;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
      } 
    }
    adjacency_list = adjacency_list->next;
  }

  return priority_list;
}

Graph_priority_t *
Graph_Dj_pop_priority_list(Graph_priority_t *priority_list) {

  Graph_priority_t      *runner;

  assert(priority_list);
  runner = priority_list;
  priority_list = priority_list->next;

  /* Destroy Unnecessary Node */
  free(runner);

  return priority_list;
}

/*
 * Function
 * Graph_get_dijkstra
 *
 * In this function we find shortest distance 
 * from Source (argument) to all the vertices
 * and distance
 *
 * Input:
 *       Graph_t * G (Graph)
 * Output:
 *       None 
 */
void
Graph_get_dijsktra(Graph_t  *G, vertex_number_t S) {
 
  Graph_vertices_t      *vertex;
  Graph_edges_t         *adjacency_list;
  Graph_priority_t      *priority_list;

  vertex = Graph_get_vertex(G,S);

  if (vertex == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Unable to find vertex %d",S);
    return;
  }
  
  vertex->min_distance = 0;
  adjacency_list = vertex->adjacency_list;
  priority_list = Graph_get_priority_list(G, priority_list, vertex);

#ifdef DEBUG
  Graph_dump_prio_list(priority_list);
#endif

  while(priority_list != NULL) {
    /* Return Last vertex from Priority List */
    vertex = Graph_Dj_get_next_vertex(G, priority_list);
    /* Pop PriorityList */
    priority_list = Graph_Dj_pop_priority_list(priority_list);
    /* Populate min distance for new vertices */
    priority_list = Graph_get_priority_list(G, priority_list,vertex); 
#ifdef DEBUG
    Graph_dump_prio_list(priority_list);
#endif
  }

  Graph_display_graph(G);

  return;
}
```

---

#### Graph.h

```
#ifndef __GRAPH_H__
#define __GRAPH_H__

/* 
 * Basic Includes
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/*
 * List of typedef
 */
typedef struct graph_ Graph_t;
typedef struct graph_vertices_ Graph_vertices_t;
typedef struct graph_edges_ Graph_edges_t;
typedef struct graph_priority_ Graph_priority_t;
typedef int vertex_number_t;
typedef int edge_weight_t;
typedef int bool;

/* 
 * This Structure maintains
 * all information regarding Graph
 */
struct graph_ {
    vertex_number_t      total_vertices; /* To Store total number of vertices */
    edge_weight_t        total_edges;    /* To Store total number of edges */
    Graph_vertices_t    *vertices_list;  /* To store vertices */
    vertex_number_t      source;         /* To Maintain Source Node */
    bool                 is_directed;    /* Set True If Graph is Directed, Else False */

};

/*
 * This Structure maintains
 * information regarding 
 * vertices in graph
 */
struct graph_vertices_ {
    vertex_number_t         interface_number;     /* To Store Vertex Index(Number) */

    bool                    is_visited;     /* To Check whether This 
                                              interface is parsed 
                                              This interface will be set False back
                                              once done with parsing */

    Graph_edges_t          *adjacency_list; /* To Maintain List of adjacent to 
                                               present vertex */
    long                    min_distance;   /* This is used to calculate 
                                               min distance from source to
                                               this vertex
                                            */
    Graph_vertices_t       *next;           /* Pointer to Next Vertex */
};

/*
 * This structure maintains
 * information regarding
 * edges in graph (Adjacency Matrix) 
 * So, This is used basing on particular vertex
 */
struct graph_edges_ {

    vertex_number_t        target; /* Target of the Edge */
    edge_weight_t          weight; /* Weight of the edge, If not given 
                                      determined as 1
                                    */
    Graph_edges_t         *next;   /* Pointer to next edge */
};

/* 
 * Graph_priority Structure
 * to maintain Priority List
 */
struct graph_priority_{
  vertex_number_t      vertex; /* To store vertex information */
  Graph_priority_t     *next;
};

/*
 * Following Defines are to Make life easy
 */
#define LOG_ERR(f_, ...)   printf("%s:%d ERROR: "f_"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO(f_, ...)  printf("%s:%d INFO:  "f_"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG(f_, ...) printf("%s:%d DEBUG: "f_"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG(f_, ...)
#endif /* DEBUG */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1

/*
 * NaN is maintain that int variable 
 * is still not available
 */
#define NaN     32767

/*
 * API Declaration
 */

Graph_t*  
Graph_init(int, bool);

Graph_vertices_t* 
Graph_add_vertices(Graph_t*, int);

void      
Graph_display_graph(const Graph_t *);

Graph_t *
Graph_add_edge(Graph_t *, vertex_number_t, vertex_number_t, edge_weight_t , bool);

void
Graph_get_dijsktra(Graph_t *, vertex_number_t );

bool
Graph_has_edge(Graph_t *, vertex_number_t , vertex_number_t);

/*
 * Misc Function Declarations
 */
bool
Graph_node_in_adjacency(Graph_edges_t *, vertex_number_t);

Graph_vertices_t *
Graph_get_vertex(Graph_t *, vertex_number_t);

#endif /* End of __GRAPH_H__ */
```

Comment: Please include the code you would like reviewed in the body of your question. We do not review off-site code here.

Comment: @PinCrash thanks for notifying ....Updated  the Question :)

Comment: Is there anything you want your review tailored towards?  Performance?  Reducing memory consumption? Etc.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late answer, but I thought I'd provide some feedback anyways. I assume since it's a library that you want other people/projects to use it, so my comments are made with that assumption as a background.

Over all, your code is clear, consistent and well laid out. There's a few things I would change though.

**I'll start with the header file:**

```
/* 
 * Basic Includes
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

You don't want these in the header file. This means that any source file including your header will also include these headers even if they have no use for it. Include what you must to make your header complete, but no more. Move the includes over to your implementation instead.

```
/*
 * List of typedef
 */
typedef struct graph_ Graph_t;
typedef struct graph_vertices_ Graph_vertices_t;
typedef struct graph_edges_ Graph_edges_t;
typedef struct graph_priority_ Graph_priority_t;
```

I'd drop the `_t`suffixes. First they don't give you anything of value when reading the code, and second [it is reserved by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225396/270280) which may or may not matter to you. In general it's best to drop it.

In fact I would even [drop the typedefs for structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4566358/270280), and just use the `struct name` whenever you need the type. I find it clearer, and it conveys useful information about what kind of type we're dealing with. (Linus [seems to agree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).) That's more a matter of taste though, and [others may disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252810/270280).

```
typedef int bool;
```

This is bad, include the `stdbool.h` header instead to use the proper `bool` defined by your standard library.

```
struct graph_ {
```

If you decide to keep the typedefs for the structs, at least keep the name of the stuct and the typedef the same. They are in different namespaces in C, so they will not interfere with each other.

```
/*
 * Following Defines are to Make life easy
 */
#define LOG_ERR(f_, ...)   printf("%s:%d ERROR: "f_"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO(f_, ...)  printf("%s:%d INFO:  "f_"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG(f_, ...) printf("%s:%d DEBUG: "f_"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG(f_, ...)
#endif /* DEBUG */
```

Logging from libraries is a bit of a pain. I would however try to find a different solution that this. As a user of the library I would want to control where logs would end up, as well as how they're formatted etc. Just blurting stuff out to stdout (or even stderr) may not work in all environments. In any case, it does not belong in the header file. It's internal to your module, so keep it in the implementation instead.

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1
```

Again, prefer to use `stdbool.h` for better portability.

```
#define NaN     32767
```

This is a very generic name, I'd probably choose something more specific to your library. How about `GRAPH_VALUE_NOT_AVAILABLE`?

**As for the source file:**

```
Graph_t G = NULL;
G   =   (Graph_t *) malloc(sizeof(Graph_t));
if (G == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Unable to allocate memory");
    goto destroy;
}
```

This construct is repeated a few times. There's a few problems with it:

1. [Don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/270280) in C.
2. The log doesn't really provide any value, just return NULL instead.
3. The `goto` statement isn't really needed, and just complicates the control flow of the function.

I'd go for this instead:

```
Graph *
Graph_init_template() {
    struct Graph *g = malloc(sizeof(Graph_t));
    if (g) {
        // initialize variable
    }

    return g;
}
```

Much more compact code, initializes the variable to it's proper value right away instead of in two steps, no goto's, no unnecessary casts, one point of return.

Apart from that I think it looks good!

And don't worry, while this may seem like a lot of comments, it's all mostly minor things. Most of the problems is with the header, which could cause problems for anyone who wants to include your library into their own project. This again seems to come from the fact that you mix library code and client code into the same source file. The issues with the header file I've pointed out would probably become a lot more obvious if you tried to use the library from a separate project instead.

Still great work! Keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

```
#include "graph.h"

/*Function:
 * Graph_node_in_adjacency
 *
 * In this function we verify whether the node is
 * present in adjacency List of a vertex
 *
 * Input:
 *      Graph_edges_t
 *      vertex_number_t
 *
 * Output:
 *      bool - True  - IF Present
 *             False - IF not Present
 */
```

Remove all redundant words from this comment.

- `Function`: it is clear that this is a function.
- `In this function we`: see above; who is `we`?
- `Input: Graph_edges_t, vertex_number_t`: These are already mentioned in the function definition, which will always be shown alongside this documentation, so in the best case you are repeating yourself, in a worse case you are providing inconsistent information.
- `Output: bool`: the `bool` is redundant.

Since you are writing this extensive documentation, you should use a tool to format it nicely. Doxygen comes to mind.

```
bool
Graph_node_in_adjacency(Graph_edges_t *adjacency_list, vertex_number_t node) {
```

The function name starts with `Graph`, but doesn't have a `Graph *` as its first argument. This is unconventional. Avoid it if possible.

Since the graph edges are not modified by this function, you should pass them as `const Graph_edges_t *adjacency_list`.

```
  Graph_edges_t         *runner;

  runner  = adjacency_list;

  while(runner != NULL) {
```

Write a space after `while`, since that is not a function name.

```
    if (runner->target == node) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    runner = runner->next;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

/*
 * Function:
 *  Graph_has_edge
 *
 * In this function we validate whether
 * there is a edge between
 * two vetices
```

typo: vetices -> vertices

```
 *
 * Input:
 *    Graph_t
 *    vertex_number_t
 *    vertex_number_t
 *
 * Output:
 *     bool True <-- If there is Edge
 *          False <-- If there is no Edge
```

In the function above you used `-` instead of `<--`. Be consistent.

```
 */
bool
Graph_has_edge(Graph_t *G, vertex_number_t S, vertex_number_t D) {
```

Variable names are usually written in lowercase.

```
  Graph_vertices_t    *vertex;

  vertex  = Graph_get_vertex(G,S);
```

The extra space from `vertex  =` should be placed between `G,S`.

```
  if (vertex == NULL) {
    LOG_DEBUG("Vertex :%d has no edges",S);
```

This space belongs before the colon, not after it.

```
    return FALSE;
  }

  return Graph_node_in_adjacency(vertex->adjacency_list,D);
```

Is it clear from the context that the graph is a directed graph? Otherwise you should mention this in the documentation.

```
}



/* Function:
 * Graph_dump_prio_list
 *
 * In this function we dump complete Priority 
 * List
 *
 * Input:
 *    Graph_priority_t *S
 *
 * Output:
 *    none
```

Well, there *is* some output. :)

```
 */
void
Graph_dump_prio_list(Graph_priority_t *S) {
```

This function should take a `FILE *` or another kind of output channel as parameter. The output should definitely not go to `stdout`, since that is reserved for the *intended* output of the *program*.

```
  ...
  printf("<-------------------->\n");


  return;
}
```

An empty `return` statement at the end of a function is useless.

```
/*
 * Function:
 * Graph_get_vertex
 *
 * In this function we vertex pointer
 * from graph
 *
 * Input:
 *      Graph_t   
 *      vertex_number_t
 *
 * Output:
 *      Graph_vertices_t
 */
Graph_vertices_t *
Graph_get_vertex(Graph_t *G, vertex_number_t node) {
```

Why is the type called `vertices_t` when it seems to represent only a single vertex? What's the difference between a `node` and a `vertex`, and why do you use both terms?

```
/*
 * Function:
 * Graph_add_edge_to_vertex
 *
 * In this function we append new_edge to
 * the adjacency list of vertices list
 *
 * Input: Graph_edges_t     adjacency_list
 *        Graph_edges_t     new_edge
 * output:
 *        Graph_edges_t* (Graph Vertex adjacencyList)
```

Use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` consistently.

Write `Output:` consistently with a capital `O`.

```
 */
Graph_edges_t *
Graph_add_edge_to_vertex(Graph_edges_t  *adjacency_list,
                         Graph_edges_t  *new_edge) {

  Graph_edges_t      *runner; /* To Parse through to vertices_list */
```

This comment doesn't make sense. Did you mean `to pass through` or `to parse through the`? Or is the comment redundant after all? You did not comment on the other `runner` variables either, so why is this an exception?

```
  if (adjacency_list == NULL) {
    free(runner);
```

Why do you free the `runner` here? You haven't initialized the variable yet, so this invokes *undefined behavior*.

```
    return new_edge;
  }

  runner = adjacency_list;

  /* Parse till we reach end of Adjacency List */
  while(runner->next != NULL) {
    runner = runner->next;
  }

  /* Append the New edge to List */
  runner->next = new_edge;

  return adjacency_list;
}
```